# Ссылка на объект

Tags: c#, классы, ссылки

Всем привет!Ситуация такая есть два класса А и Б. В классе А мы создаем объект, допустим List. В классе Б мы пытаемся обратиться к объекту чтобы получить значение в одном из полей. Нам говорят объект нестатический нужно либо сделать его статическим, либо прописать ссылку на объект. Я сделал его статическим,но потом появилась проблема, я не могу менять его содержимое. Есть у нас список

```
 List<Line> DA = new List<Line>();
```

И нужно заменить значение поля A.DA[i].number, но мне не позволяют это сделать потому что объект статический. Мой вопрос как прописывать ссылку на объект или как можно обойти и заменить значение этого поля другим?

Comment: Очень коряво излагаете. Код лучше покажите.

Comment: Вот так 

    class A
    {
     struct Data{
     int x;
     int y;
     public Data(int x,inty){
     this.x=x;
     this.y=y;}
     }
     List<Data> QQ= new List<Data>();
         }
     class B
     {
     i=2;
     A.QQ.RemoveAt(i)
     A.QQ[i].x= 23;
     }

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, Ваш код, а то Ваша формулировка несколько пространственна


Comment: Я в комментарии написал...

Comment: просто лень прописывать весь код, там с консоли вводится все. Это ни имеет отношения к моему вопросу. Я спрашиваю про ссылки на объект.

Comment: A.QQ.RemoveAt(i) - после выполнения этой операции элемента с индексом i не существует. Ну а если не обращать внимание на эту деталь, то попробуйте что-то вроде этого
A.Data obj=new A.Data();
obj.x=23;
A.QQ.Add(obj);

Comment: сейчас попробую, да  я торопился когда писал, просто у меня код уже на 500 строчек все сюда переносить нет смысла.

Comment: или так
A.Data obj=new A.Data(); obj.x=23; A.QQ.Insert(i,obj);

Comment: можно делать копию объекта QQ
List<A.Data> newQQ=A.QQ

Comment: Метод Insert смещает или заменят?Имеется ввиду если допустим длина списка 5 и мы пропишем метод Insert() то длина станет 6?

Comment: Да, длина станет 6, но вы перед этим удаляете i-й элемент, поэтому длина фактически не изменится. Т.е длина была 5, вы удалили элемент, она стала 4, затем добавили и снова 5